# Dynamic column mapping ADF, need only few columns

Tags: dynamic, copy, mapping, azure-data-factory

I have a set of tables that need to be copied from one database to another and I am passing the json mapping dynamically. For some of the tables, I need only few columns and I mapped the ones that I need. But it's giving me the error for the columns that I have not mapped.

This is the error I am getting for Table1, column 'Type' is there in the source but not in the destination. I don't want this column, so I did not map this.
Column 'Type' does not exist in the table 'Table1',
The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination.

Please can someone advise

Answer (score 0):

> column 'Type' is there in the source but not in the destination. Column 'Type' does not exist in the table 'Table1'

**The above errors you are facing is because of incorrect Colum names or its case sensitivity. ensure using correct column names.**

I tried to copy only few columns from source to destination and it worked.

**My mapping json:**

```json
{
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "mappings": [
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "name": "Name",
                                    "type": "String",
                                    "physicalType": "varchar"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Name",
                                    "type": "String",
                                    "physicalType": "varchar"
                                }
                            }
```

[image]

**Coping only selected columns in destination:**

[image]